# Oracle SQL to filter High out of normal values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have sample data as below and I wanted to filter/identify out of normal values. Not sure how to EXCLUDE OUTLIER values in a SQL construct. Tried taking average(Sal), but not sure how to exclude those high values from average?

```
    date   dept_id  Sal
    201907   10     250
    201907   10     290
    201907   10     320
    201907   10     100000
    201907   10     500000
    201908   20     800
    201908   20     860
    201908   20     700
    201908   20     850000
    201908   20     1000000
    201909   10     260
    201909   10     230
    201909   10     310
```

Expected Output as below

```
    date   dept_id  Sal     out_of_normal_values
    201907   10     250         N
    201907   10     290         N
    201907   10     320         N
    201907   10     100000      Y   
    201907   10     500000      Y
    201908   20     800         N 
    201908   20     860         N
    201908   20     700         N
    201908   20     850000      Y
    201908   20     1000000     Y
    201909   10     260         N
    201909   10     230         N
    201909   10     310         N
```

Comment: Typically, if you are expecting a normal distribution of values you can count outliers as being 2 or 3 standard deviations from the mean. How would you describe your expected data set? A normal distribution, a Poisson distribution, something else? Because, if you know your expected distribution then you can look for methods of identifying outliers from that distribution.

Comment: @stackuser . . . Are you asking for methods to identify outliers or do you have something in mind?  Can the outliers be on the *low* side as well as the *high* side?  Can you explain what the *real* problem is?  For instance, is the issue that some salaries are inserted in the wrong currency?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The issue is that we have a single table that captures daily sales and loans and we wanted to filter all loans.. so generally our loans will be quite high compared to actual sales ex:- sale value is ~38877.82 and loan is ~1073173 and we wanted to filter all loans

Comment: @stackuser . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question with more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create CASE statement as following

```
case
    when
        sal > 1000
    then
        'Y'
    else
        'N'
end as out_of_normal_values
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` and `group by` to get the desired result

```
select a.date, b.dept_id, a.sal,
    case
        when b.avg_sal < a.sal then 'Y'
        else 'N'
    end as out_of_normal
from tbl a join (
    select dept_id, avg(sal) avg_sal from tbl
    group by dept_id
) b on a.dept_id = b.dept_id
```

Comment: If you have salary alternating `250` then `300` across all rows then this will exclude half the rows. This is more a problem with the OP's data set; however blindly excluding values that are less than the mean you should expect about half the values to be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the values that are within two standard deviations of the mean then you can use analytic functions (and avoid having to use a self-join):

```sql
SELECT dt,
       dept_id,
       sal,
       CASE
       WHEN sal BETWEEN avg_sal - 2 * stddev_sal
                AND     avg_sal + 2 * stddev_sal
       THEN 'N'
       ELSE 'Y'
       END AS out_of_normal_values
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         AVG( sal ) OVER () AS avg_sal,
         STDDEV( sal ) OVER () AS stddev_sal
  FROM   table_name t
);
```

Which for your data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE  table_name ( dt, dept_id, Sal ) AS
SELECT 201907,   10,     250 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201907,   10,     290 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201907,   10,     320 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201907,   10,     100000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201907,   10,     500000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201908,   20,     800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201908,   20,     860 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201908,   20,     700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201908,   20,     850000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201908,   20,     1000000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201909,   10,     260 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201909,   10,     230 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201909,   10,     310 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>     DT | DEPT_ID |     SAL | OUT_OF_NORMAL_VALUES
> -----: | ------: | ------: | :-------------------
> 201907 |      10 |     250 | N                   
> 201907 |      10 |     290 | N                   
> 201907 |      10 |     320 | N                   
> 201907 |      10 |  100000 | N                   
> 201907 |      10 |  500000 | N                   
> 201908 |      20 |     800 | N                   
> 201908 |      20 |     860 | N                   
> 201908 |      20 |     700 | N                   
> 201908 |      20 |  850000 | N                   
> 201908 |      20 | 1000000 | Y                   
> 201909 |      10 |     260 | N                   
> 201909 |      10 |     230 | N                   
> 201909 |      10 |     310 | N
> ```

Which has excluded the most extreme value; if you had a larger data set then this would likely be more effective as you will have a greater proportion of "normal" values to "outliers". However, because you have a small data set with two widely separated peaks of data then the mean lies between them and you have a huge standard deviation.

If you want know the outliers are going to be high then you could use the median instead of the mean and look for values that are between the minimum and the median or up to an equal value above the median:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       dept_id,
       sal,
       CASE
       WHEN sal BETWEEN min_sal
                AND     median_sal + ( median_sal - min_sal )
       THEN 'N'
       ELSE 'Y'
       END AS out_of_normal_values
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MEDIAN( sal ) OVER () AS median_sal,
         MIN(sal) OVER () AS min_sal
  FROM   table_name t
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
>     DT | DEPT_ID |     SAL | OUT_OF_NORMAL_VALUES
> -----: | ------: | ------: | :-------------------
> 201909 |      10 |     230 | N                   
> 201907 |      10 |     250 | N                   
> 201909 |      10 |     260 | N                   
> 201907 |      10 |     290 | N                   
> 201909 |      10 |     310 | N                   
> 201907 |      10 |     320 | N                   
> 201908 |      20 |     700 | N                   
> 201908 |      20 |     800 | N                   
> 201908 |      20 |     860 | N                   
> 201907 |      10 |  100000 | Y                   
> 201907 |      10 |  500000 | Y                   
> 201908 |      20 |  850000 | Y                   
> 201908 |      20 | 1000000 | Y
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06b491f961fce94cae6b7d6d637ae94c)*

Comment: This is awesome 99% working. I have modified the actual range coming form our system here [fiddle] (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ec48f2bf21401e9a875b61bf69693c34) and i see an exception for value "1073173" which should be marked as out_of_normal_values.. any thoughts on how to make this more robust??

Comment: @stackuser Have a larger data set. As with most statistics, you don't get the best answers if you have a tiny sample size. You only have 8 rows so the median value is going to be half way between the 4th and 5th values. Add another low value [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d82faa059c27398b6f23560daa777538) and your problem row is excluded.

Comment: Thank you for ur time. So (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6b7d84c783e86a18fa66156ed58ee686)

Comment: @stackuser I can't give you an answer that will work 100% of the time because i do not have your data and do not understand your data set. You appear to have a data set with two peaks in it so you need to do something like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36309/how-do-i-find-peaks-in-a-dataset and then set your boundary between the two peaks. What you really need to do is compile a sufficiently large data set that is representative of your problem and then ask a new question with sufficient detail that someone with a detailed statistics knowledge can help you.

Comment: My only other suggestion is to change your data model; if you want to eliminate loan values then you should have another column in your table which indicates whether your value is a loan or a sale and then you can use that to have a simple `WHERE` filter to remove the rows and you don't need to try to perform a complicates statistical analysis of the data set.

Comment: Totally Agree.. so far you have been outstanding.. I'm now trying ML KNN/LOF etc, to knock this out.

Comment: Sir, so i have good success in using local outlier factors (LOF) with euclidean-distance and filtering anything greater than >50 using ML platform (but we dont have ML platfrom in our compay), as such was trying to see how we can do similar query here, so that I can apply to your logic to calculate the euclidean-distance? I found some reference here, but couldn't get this working stackoverflow.com/questions/39892453/euclidean-distance/… .. here is our orginal query dbfiddle.uk/…, can u plz help construct a euclidean-distance

Comment: @stackuser Please ask a new question with all the details there. Make sure you include your sample data, the link to the DBfiddle you're using and what you expect the output to be and you should get answers there and I'll try and look at in a separate question if I can.